# Why can't I setup a root user for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, root

I'm trying to start my first database project, and am trying to setup a root user. However, whenever I do it, this comes up:

[image: Error]

I tried opening the server, as is shown in the above, but that didn't work either. Can someone help me fix this? Thanks.

Comment: is that for mysql or just ubuntu?

Comment: @JNevill He's not asking about the Unix root user, he's asking about the MySQL root user. They're not related.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: @Barmar you are correct. I've got my wires crossed today.

Comment: the problem is that i've never assigned a root password, and the teminal line for that outputs the error

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of mysql, mariadb and perconadb all use [so_peercred](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/socket-pluggable-authentication.html) to authenticate users in the absence of a password (i.e. the initial state). Try:

```
sudo mysqladmin -u root password s3cr3t
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it does anything, it just says [Warning] Using a password on the comandline interface can be insecure \n Warning: Since password will be sent to server in plain text, use ssl connection to ensure password safety.

Comment: Yes, and what happenned next? ("Warning" means the system did what you aked but the system thinks you might not hav eintended what you asked for. Sending passwords in clear text across a network is a bad idea - but since the network segment is entirely contained within the host in this instance there shouldn't be any risk).

Comment: i figured it out another way, apparently there was no password so that i just had to do sudo mysql -u root and press enter when it asked for password, then set it up later. however, when I was trying it your way it didn't set any password, even though i put like "root" after it to test, so i'm not sure.